# Get accurate probabilities associated to binary classification

Tags: python, keras, classification

I have a binary classification model in Keras (TF) with loss = binary_crossentropy and activation='sigmoid' for last layer. So far so good..

I'm getting the probabilities with predict_proba.

I was expecting that retreived probabilities (I'm not actualy interested in classification, just the proba) would match real ones.
It is not the case as we can see on two samples here from two datasets/models (actual proba vs computed)

[image: sample 1]
[image: sample 2]

My question: how can I get accurate probabilities? Recalibration? Other way of doing?

Thanks

Comment: whats the exact meaning of accurate probabilities ?

Comment: For me it would mean values on the graph will have the same x value (real probability) vs Y value (predicted). We can see on the 2nd figure that for a X near 0.2 we have a Y near 0.4. Both X and Y should be the same.